# insert into when select not matching

Tags: postgresql, insert-into

I have this query :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1(id , name)
SELECT  id, 'XXX' 
FROM tbl_2 t WHERE t.name='XXX';
```

it's working when the SELECT clause match. I would like to execute the insert query with 0 in "id" field even when the SELECT does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your query in a subselect (therefore it will always return at least one value):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1(id , name)
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT id FROM tbl_2 t WHERE t.name='XXX'), 0), 'XXX';
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1(id , name)
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT id FROM tbl_2 t WHERE t.name=v.name), 0), v.name
FROM (VALUES ('XXX')) v(name);
```

Comment: Thx for all but this one is faster :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION` which has the advantage that the number of rows returned by the "base" select is not limited to one:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (id , name)
SELECT id, 'XXX' 
FROM tbl_2 t 
WHERE t.name='XXX'
union all
select 0, 'XXX'
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_2 t where t.name = 'XXX');
```